# phonegap sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27206 of [42537b6056]

Tags: android, cordova

Getting error: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27206 of [42537b6056] when i run my phonegap app on my htc

my js looks like this:
    var db;

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("DB1", "1.0", "DB1 name", 65536);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what permissions do you have in the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore this error:

"sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 27206"

It Will not produce any issues for you.

**UPDATE:**
Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<!-- Adding Phonegap scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova/cordova-1.5.0.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onDeviceReady() {

}
function showAlert() {
    alert("Not yet implemented");
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="user" style="width:140px">
</div>
<div>
  Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" style=
  "width:140px">
</div><span id="loginbutton" data-role="button" data-icon="check"
data-inline="true" data-theme="b" onclick="showAlert()">Login</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem is that later i have the following:

 $("#loginbutton").click(function() {
  alert("login fired");
 });

wich does not fires, probably because of this


and i will need the database, i'll gtry to write in it, or read from it later

Comment: @LaszloCsiki Where are you place your this code which is not firing?

Comment: in my index.html i have:

<div>Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="user" style="width:140px" /></div>
<div>Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" style="width:140px" /></div>
<span id="loginbutton" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Login</span>

Comment: @LaszloCsiki Tick the Answer Right so that others can take proper reference from this...:)